# Filling pandas dataframe with foreign key

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables: master, summary, controller.

master contains the columns: asset_id(unique), controller_name

controller contains the columns: controller_id which is a primary key generated based on unique controller_names

summary contains the columns: asset_id(primary key) and controller_id(empty)

I need to find a way to fill the controller_id table based on it's asset id.

For Example:

If the Master table looked like this:

[image: Master]

This would be the corresponding Controller table:

[image: Controller]

This is what I want the Summary table to look like

[image: Summary]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hey Buddy, welcome to SO, can you create a viable example for us? please add in an example subset of your tables (in text not pictures) and your expected outcome, along with what you've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) merge on `controller_id`

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas merge and select the columns of interest

```
summary = master.merge(
    controller,
    on='controller_name',
    how='left'
)[['asset_id','controller_id']]
```